# How to pass form id to insetListing components dataprovider in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module

I want to add affected products listing inside **catalog price rule** form.

I have followed related product example to do the same.

Same as related products I have added insertListing component inside catalog form components XML file for affected product listing like below.

```
<insertListing>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">affected_product_listing</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">affected_product_listing</item>
                <item name="externalProvider" xsi:type="string">affected_product_listing.affected_product_listing.affected_product_listing_data_source</item>
                <item name="selectionsProvider" xsi:type="string">affected_product_listing.affected_product_listing.product_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="render_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="realTimeLink" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="behaviourType" xsi:type="string">simple</item>
                <item name="externalFilterMode" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataLinks" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="exports" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
                <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="rule_id" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:data.rule_id</item>
                </item>
                <item name="exports" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="rule_id" xsi:type="string">${ $.externalProvider }:params.rule_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </insertListing>
```

I have added another ui component and data provider for grid **affected_product_listing**

In my dataprovider i have printed request params like this :-

```
public function getData()
{
    $catalogPriceRuleId = $this->request->getParams();
    print_r($catalogPriceRuleId);
    exit;
    $rule = $this->rule->load(2);  /* catalog price rule id */
    $productIdsArray = $rule->getMatchingProductIds();
    $productIdsArray = array_keys($productIdsArray);

    if (!$this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
        $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIdsArray])->load();
    }
    $items = $this->getCollection()->toArray();

    $data = [
        'totalRecords' => $this->getCollection()->getSize(),
        'items' => array_values($items),
    ];

    /** @var ModifierInterface $modifier */
    foreach ($this->modifiersPool->getModifiersInstances() as $modifier) {
        $data = $modifier->modifyData($data);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Now the issue is I am not getting **catalog rule id** here in request params.

So I want to pass **catalog price rule id** in insertListing components dataprovider to fetch only affected products of this particular catalog price rule, So how can I pass it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you solved this?

Comment: @ReniRajNR Yes its resolved.

Comment: @DeepJoshi How did you resolve this ?

Comment: @DeepJoshi Can you add an answer on how you achieved this? I am facing the same issue in passing a "parent id" to the grid to filter but cannot get the ID into the data provider. Many hours spent on google. Your answer would be most, most appreciated.